# Customizing Comments on Posts

Tags: posts, pagination, comments

I have implemented custom code for generating comments on post page using callback function in `functions.php`.

```
function MYTHEME_comment($comment, $args, $depth) {
   $GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment; ?>

<li <?php comment_class(); ?> id="li-comment-<?php comment_ID() ?>">
   <div class="comment-author vcard">
     <?php echo get_avatar($comment,$size='48' ); ?>
       <div class="comment-meta"><a href="<?php the_author_meta( 'user_url'); ?>"><?php printf(__('%s'), get_comment_author_link()) ?></a></div>
     </div>
     <div class="clear"></div>

     <?php if ($comment->comment_approved == '0') : ?>
       <em><?php _e('Your comment is awaiting moderation.') ?></em>
       <br />
     <?php endif; ?>

     <div class="comment-text"> 
         <?php comment_text() ?>
     </div>

   <div class="reply">
      <?php comment_reply_link(array_merge( $args, array('depth' => $depth, 'max_depth' => $args['max_depth']))) ?>
       <span class="comment-date"> <?php printf(__('%1$s at %2$s'), get_comment_date(),  get_comment_time()) ?><?php edit_comment_link(__('(Edit)'),'  ','') ?></span>
   </div>
```

Here is a pastebin of the same code http://pastebin.com/nUjvsFua

It generates basic code to show all the comments on that post.
I want the first five comments to be shown and then a "View more" button to show remaining comments. Any guide on how can I achieve this?

Comment: That code only displays one comment, you have to loop it 5 times then show a read more link.

Comment: That function is called by wordpress for each comment. Iis is called by wp_list_comments( array( 'callback' => 'MYTHEME_comment' ) )

Answer (score 0):

Set `per_page` to 5 and `page` to 1 in `wp_list_comments`

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments

Then add your read more link just below your comments to reload the page with `per_page` and `page` not set. You can do this with AJAX for smoothness.

Comment: It is working partially. setting per_page to '5' and page to '1', it displays oldest 5 comments but I want to show newest 5 comments. Setting reverse_top_level to true or false also doesn't help. /any idea how can I go about this?